# How can I merge 2 observables in a custom fashion?

Tags: rx-java2

Custom fashion is:
`obs1 = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]`, `obs2 = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]` -> `mergedObs = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]`

I was thinking about `obs1.zipWith(obs2)` and my bifunction was `(a, b) -> Observable.just(a, b)` and then it's not trivial for me to flatten `Observable<Observable<Integer>>`.

Comment: `merge` operator

Comment: I believe `.merge` doesn't guarantee the exact order.

Comment: use the `concat` operator, it preserves order

Comment: Well, that's the reason I asked this question. I don't want '111222' or some random order. I want '121212'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That looks like an ordered merge: merge so that the smallest is picked from the sources when they all have items ready:

[Flowables.orderedMerge()](https://github.com/akarnokd/RxJava2Extensions#flowablesorderedmerge):

> Given a fixed number of input sources (which can be self-comparable or given a `Comparator`) merges them into a single stream by repeatedly picking the smallest one from each source until all of them completes.

```java
Flowables.orderedMerge(Flowable.just(1, 3, 5), Flowable.just(2, 4, 6))
.test()
.assertResult(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);
```

**Edit**

If the sources are guaranteed to be the same length, you can also `zip` them into a structure and then flatten that:

```java
Observable.zip(source1, source2, (a, b) -> Arrays.asList(a, b))
.flatMapIterable(list -> list)
;
```

Comment: Well, it looks good, but is there any reasonable simple workaround without using rare operators?

Comment: If the length of the sources are different, you need a custom operator.

Comment: Let's say I can guarantee the length is the same.

Comment: And actually my merging is more similar to [1, 2, 3], [0, 0, 0] -> [1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0] if it makes the difference.

Comment: Updated the answer.